# Bank account class simulator with possible exception

Tags: python, object-oriented

I'm a newbie to python object oriented programming, Unfortunately in all the ways, Classes that I write turn into a true mess.

I'd be glad if someone would be able to point me some of my mistakes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def main():

    from decimal import Decimal
    from typing import List


    class BankDespositLimitError(Exception):
        def __init__(self, traceback: str, amount: Decimal, bank_limit: Decimal):
            """Bank does not support the current desposited amount Error

            # Args:
                - traceback (str): The traceback message.
                - amount (Decimal): The amount tried to be desposited
                - bank_limit (Decimal): The top amount the bank support for desposit.
            """

            self.amount = ''.join([character for character in str(amount) if character.isdigit()])
            self.bank_limit = bank_limit
            self.traceback = f'{traceback} \nGiven amount : {self.amount} | Top supported amount : {self.bank_limit}'
            super().__init__(self.traceback)


    class InvalidCurrencyError(Exception):
        def __init__(
            self, traceback: str, inputted_currency: str, avaliable_currencies: List[str]
        ):
            """
            Args:
                traceback (str): The desired error message
                inputted_currency (str): The currency that the user have entered.
                avaliable_currencies (List[str]): The bank avaliable currencies.
            """

            __ac_isstr = list(
                map(lambda element: isinstance(element, str), avaliable_currencies)
            )

            if not all(__ac_isstr):
                raise ValueError("Avaliable currencies must be strings.")

            if not isinstance(inputted_currency, str):
                raise ValueError("inputted currency must be string.")

            if not isinstance(traceback, str):
                raise ValueError("The traceback must be a string.")

            self.inputted_currency = inputted_currency.lower()
            self.avaliable_currencies = [currency.lower() for currency in avaliable_currencies]
            self.traceback = (
                f"{traceback}| \n"
                f"inputted currency : {self.inputted_currency} \n"
                f"avaliable currencies : {', '.join(self.avaliable_currencies)}"
            )

            super().__init__(self.traceback)


    class Account:
        def __init__(
            self, first_name: str, last_name: str, balance: Decimal, currency: str
        ) -> None:
            """`Initialize a bank account ( Simple form )`

            # Args:
                - first_name (`str`): The account owner first name.
                - last_name (`str`): The account owner last name.
                - balance (`Decimal`): the account owner balance.
                - currency (`str`): The account currency (`dollar`, `toman`)
            """

            __bank_limit = Decimal(1000)
            __supported_currencies = ["toman", "dollar"]
            currency = currency.lower()
            first_name = first_name.lower()
            last_name = last_name.lower()

            if not isinstance(first_name, str):
                raise ValueError(
                    f"Expected first_name argument type (str), not ({type(first_name).__name__})"
                )

            if not isinstance(last_name, str):
                raise ValueError(
                    f"Expected last_name argument type (str), not ({type(last_name).__name__})"
                )

            if not isinstance(balance, Decimal):
                raise ValueError(
                    f"Expected balance argument type (Decimal), not ({type(balance).__name__})"
                )

            if not isinstance(currency, str):
                raise ValueError(
                    f"Expected currency argument type (str), not ({type(currency).__name__})"
                )

            if not currency in __supported_currencies:
                raise InvalidCurrencyError(
                    "That currency is not supported by this bank at the moment.",
                    currency,
                    __supported_currencies,
                )

            if balance < 0:
                raise ValueError("The account balance cannot be a negative number.")

            if balance > __bank_limit:
                raise BankDespositLimitError(
                    "The bank not support this amount of first desposit at the moment.",
                    balance,
                    __bank_limit,
                )
            
            self.first_name = first_name
            self.last_name = last_name
            self.full_name = f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
            self.balance = balance
            self.currency = currency    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The `if __name__` main() guard is very nice, I thank you kindly. But `import` and `class` definitions within `def main():` is just bizarre. Please revise the question so we see imports at top-of-module, and `class` definitions also at top-level. That will let reviewers focus on the substance of what you have to say, rather than odd details of how you say it.

Comment: @J_H If OP learned Python by putting `import`s and `classe`s inside their `def main`, that is definitely something that needs to be addressed in an answer, preferably with rationale. Not something to be treated as "please format your question better".

Comment: The irony is that - despite there being so much code in `main()` - _nothing is ever run_. There are no tests or demos that exercise the code. Do you have something like this that you can include?

Answer (score 4):

### The good

Docstrings!

Custom exception types with contextual parameters!

Validation!

`Decimal` for currency!

### The bad

It's *deposit*, not *desposit* (the bank, despite our occasional grievances, is not a despot).

It's *available*, not *avaliable*.

It's not terrible to use `List` but it's outdated. Update Python and then just use `list`.

What you're calling a traceback is extremely not a traceback; it's just an error message.

The gymnastics around `self.amount = ''.join` should go away; just store the member directly.

Python is a duck-typed language (to our collective detriment). That means that "if it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it is a duck". It's therefore less important (and usually futile) to do run-time type checking. More important is run-time *value* checking like your negative and limit checks; and static analysis of types using Mypy.

It doesn't make sense to do any of these checks:

```py
            __ac_isstr = list(
                map(lambda element: isinstance(element, str), avaliable_currencies)
            )

            if not all(__ac_isstr):
                raise ValueError("Avaliable currencies must be strings.")
```

because in theory, the available list of currencies is enforced by the application or bank, not provided by the user - so of course they'll all be valid. If you were to instantiate a `Bank` class this might change.

The format of your docstrings is one I don't recognize. Prefer something standard, either RestructuredText (default from PyCharm), Doxygen, etc.

Don't repeat the parameter type in your docstring; keep it to your typehint only.

Add tests.

Consider representing `full_name` as a `@property`.

Move your bank limit and supported currency variables to statics on the class.

Don't lowercase your first and last names.

### The ugly

Don't wrap your entire program in `main()` - `main()` should only have entry-point code. In my demonstration I show it calling into a test. De-tab everything else.

Variables like `__ac_isstr` should not be double-underscored - that's reserved for a different meaning.

### Suggested

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from decimal import Decimal


class DepositLimitError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, deposit: Decimal, bank_limit: Decimal) -> None:
        self.deposit = deposit
        self.bank_limit = bank_limit
        super().__init__(f'Deposit attempted: {self.deposit} | Deposit limit: {self.bank_limit}')


class InvalidCurrencyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, input_currency: str) -> None:
        self.input_currency = input_currency
        super().__init__(f'Currency {input_currency} is not supported.')


class Account:
    DEPOSIT_LIMIT = Decimal(1_000)
    SUPPORTED_CURRENCIES = {'toman', 'dollar'}

    def __init__(
        self, first_name: str, last_name: str, balance: Decimal = 0, currency: str = 'dollar',
    ) -> None:
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError('First name must be a non-empty string')
        self.first_name = first_name

        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError('Last name must be a non-empty string')
        self.last_name = last_name

        if currency not in self.SUPPORTED_CURRENCIES:
            raise InvalidCurrencyError(currency)
        self.currency = currency

        if balance < 0:
            raise ValueError('The account balance must be non-negative.')
        if balance > self.DEPOSIT_LIMIT:
            raise DepositLimitError(balance, self.DEPOSIT_LIMIT)
        self.balance = balance

    @property
    def full_name(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'


def test() -> None:
    try:
        Account('', 'Bill')
        raise AssertionError()
    except ValueError:
        pass

    try:
        Account('Joe', '')
        raise AssertionError()
    except ValueError:
        pass

    try:
        Account('Joe', 'Bill', -3)
        raise AssertionError()
    except ValueError:
        pass

    try:
        Account('Joe', 'Bill', 10_000)
        raise AssertionError()
    except DepositLimitError:
        pass

    try:
        Account('Joe', 'Bill', Decimal(500), 'lira')
        raise AssertionError()
    except InvalidCurrencyError:
        pass

    account = Account('Joe', 'Bill', Decimal(600), 'dollar')
    assert account.full_name == 'Joe Bill'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Yay, unit tests! Those are valuable, very nice. Some folks like `-m unittest`, some prefer `pytest` or other runners. Me? I like 'em both, so I tend to inherit from TestCase, giving the flexibility to choose a runner weeks later according to need. (I find `$ pytest --cov` a very convenient way to measure code coverage.) In these tests, I feel that [with self.assertRaises(DepositLimitError):](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) offers slightly clearer exposition. Plus, you can't accidentally omit `raise AssertionError()` and admit "silent success".

Comment: Or `import pytest`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29855337/how-do-i-properly-assert-that-an-exception-gets-raised-in-pytest

Comment: Sure? But I tried to keep it simple since OP self-describes as a newbie.

Comment: Greetings, Thanks for your answer sir it was pretty much helpful to me as a beginner, Just in case you asked, the docstring format is the [Google docstring](https://gist.github.com/redlotus/3bc387c2591e3e908c9b63b97b11d24e) format, if we despite the small changes I've inserted to them.